# Sum of Primes using Sieve of Eratosthenes can't find bug

Tags: javascript, sum, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I'm working in JavaScript and this is a bit confusing because the code is returning the correct sum of primes. It is working with larger numbers. There is a bug where for 977 it returns the sum of primes for 976, which is 72179, instead of the sum for 977 which is 73156. Everything I've test so far has come back correctly.

```
function sumPrimes(num) {

    var sum = 0;
    var count = 0;
    var array = [];
    var upperLimit = Math.sqrt(num);
    var output = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        array.push(true);
    }

    for (var j = 2; j <= upperLimit; j++) {
        if (array[j]) {
            for (var h = j * j; h < num; h += j) {
                array[h] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    for (var k = 2; k < num; k++) {
        if (array[k]) {
            output.push(k);
        }
    }

    for (var a = 0; a < output.length; a++) {
        sum += output[a];
        count++;
    }

    return sum;
}

sumPrimes(977);
```

Comment: Please don't be lazy when formatting your question

Comment: @Amit Done with formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem stems from the fact that your "seive" `Array` is indexed from 0, but your algorithm assumes that `array[n]` represents the number `n`.

Since you want `array[n]===true` to mean that `n` is prime, you need an `Array` of length `978` if you want the last item to be indexed as `array[977]` and *mean* the number `977`.

The issue seems to be fixed when I change all instances of `< num` to `< num+1`.